# Strange work or two-parameter form of messager.printMessage

Tags: java, eclipse, annotations, annotation-processing, annotations-processing-messager

According to [Java.doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javax/annotation/processing/Messager.html), `Messager` has 4 footprints of printMessage:

```
printMessage​(Diagnostic.Kind kind, CharSequence msg)
printMessage​(Diagnostic.Kind kind, CharSequence msg, Element e)
printMessage​(Diagnostic.Kind kind, CharSequence msg, Element e, AnnotationMirror a)
printMessage​(Diagnostic.Kind kind, CharSequence msg, Element e, AnnotationMirror a, AnnotationValue v)
```

The Interface of the annotation is:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.CLASS)
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
public @interface AddBuilder {
    public boolean lazyBuild() default false;
}
```

I want it to work only with non-abstract class and check for the abstractness in the `Processor`. The reason is: *I want to know how can I make checks in the processor*.

---

The second variant works:

```
public boolean process(Set<? extends TypeElement> annotations, RoundEnvironment roundEnv) {
    Set<? extends Element> classesForBuilder = roundEnv.getElementsAnnotatedWith(AddBuilder.class);
    for(Element classElement : classesForBuilder){
        if (classElement.getModifiers().contains(Modifier.ABSTRACT)  ) {
            messager.printMessage(Kind.ERROR, "AnnoBuilder cannot be applied to an abstract class.", classElement);
            return true;
        }
...
```

The error is seen on the annotated element and in `Problems` view

[image]

, but not seen in the Errors Log.

---

If I use the first form, expecting to find the error in Problems or Error Log:

```
public boolean process(Set<? extends TypeElement> annotations, RoundEnvironment roundEnv) {
    messager.printMessage(Kind.ERROR, "Some problem with annotations.");
    return true;
```

- No problems are seen at all, in  Problems or in the source file. And the Error Log has the "Some problem with annotations." line, but it is not error, or at least warning, but an **info** line. In the real life such line will be surely overlooked. How can I make Eclipse to show the error as **error**?